# Drupal 7: Adding a private forum to an organic group

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, forum, organic-groups

I'm wondering what is the best way to do the following.

I have a private group, and on the group's home page, I want a submenu of pages which belong to the group.

Primarily, the group has to have a private forum when which selected, will display a list of topics, but only to members of the group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Organic Group form Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/og_forum_D7) module for creating forum specific to group only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Organic Groups, but if you want a forum, perhaps take a look at [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) and [Forum Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access) (permissions).  Otherwise, you might be able to accomplish a similar feature simply with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: At this point (d7,201110) advanced forum and organic groups dont really cooperate. a forum is not a content type and cant be configured to use og groups fields. you can limit forum topics using og group fields, but it gives errors here. previously, there was a module named og_forum, but it has been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Forum Access module to do this. Although, I guess, if you had multiple forums you would have to setup more roles based on the OG they belonged to.